# webpack-dev-server error when deploying react/node app to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm having issues deploying a React/Express app to Heroku. I'm getting a "Webpack-dev-server not found" error, though I don't think I'm using the dev-server anymore, as I started using my node server.

[Picture of Heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUvQi.png)

Below is my package.json (just dev dependencies)

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon tools/publicServer.js -d --config 
              webpack.config.prod.js --content-base dist/ --progress --colors",
    "clean": "npm run remove && mkdir dist",
    "remove": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
    "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean build:html",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node tools/publicServer.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "3.2.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "10.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.0.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "morgan": "^1.8.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0.0",
    "npm": ">=3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Below is my build.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

console.log('Generating minified bundle for production via Webpack...'.blue);

webpack(webpackConfig).run((err, stats) => {
  if (err) { // so a fatal error occurred. Stop here.
    console.log(err.bold.red);
    return 1;
  }

  const jsonStats = stats.toJson();

  if (jsonStats.hasErrors) {
    return jsonStats.errors.map(error => console.log(error.red));
  }

  if (jsonStats.hasWarnings) {
    console.log('Webpack generated the following warnings: '.bold.yellow);
    jsonStats.warnings.map(warning => console.log(warning.yellow));
  }

  console.log(`Webpack stats: ${stats}`);
  console.log('Your app has been compiled in production mode and written to /dist.'.green);

  return 0;
});
```

Below is my buildHtml.js

```
import fs from 'fs';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
import colors from 'colors';

/*eslint-disable no-console */

fs.readFile('src/index.html', 'utf8', (err, markup) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  const $ = cheerio.load(markup);
  $('head').prepend('');

  fs.writeFile('dist/index.html', $.html(), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('index.html written to /dist'.green);
  });
});
```

Below is my publicService.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var open = require('open');
var compression = require('compression');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

/*eslint-disable no-console */

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

I'm kind of new to this, I'd really appreciate any input, thanks very much!

EDIT: Here's my webpack.config.prod

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        // 'react-hot-loader/patch',
        // 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        // 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        // './index.js'
        '../src/index.js'
    ],

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    // 
    // devServer: {
    //     hot: true,
    //     contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    //     publicPath: '/',
    //     historyApiFallback: true
    // },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(net|http|child_process|timers|dns|fs|zlib)$/)
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` is set to `true` on Heroku so `devDependecies` are not installed. 
You should move the dependencies that you need in your production build to `dependencies` or set `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to false (not recommended):

`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`.

By the way, you should create a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and declare what commands are run by your application's dynos and use `node` instead of `nodemon` to run your server:

`web: node tools/publicServer.js -d --config webpack.config.prod.js --content-base dist/ --progress --colors`

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! After trying all of this, I'm getting the same (albeit shorter) error message (before it was the same error coming up multiple times, now it's just coming up once). Any idea on how to handle this? I'm mostly confused that it's giving me the "werbpack-dev-server not found" error, but I'm fairly certain that all references to the dev server have been removed from my code. Thank you again for the input

Comment: I think webpack `run` method needs the dev server. You may try moving this dependency to dependencies or using `heroku-prebuild` hook to run your build process.

Comment: Hmmm bummer, still no luck and getting the same errors.. This is bizarre, probably something foolish I've done, thank you very much for the answer though - I'll keep chugging along to try and rectify this.